# This filter is not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, filter

```
function get20(arr){
 let result = arr.filter((theArtist) => {
   let birth = Number(theArtist.years.splice(0,3))
   let death = Number(theArtist.years.splice(7,10))
   return birth >= 1900 && death <= 2000;
  })
 return result;
}
```

This keeps giving me the error "theArtist.years.splice is not a function" I do not understand why it isn't taking the first four and last four letters of the "years" string and turning them into numbers. the years string looks like "1971 - 1984"

Comment: Because `splice` is an array function?

Comment: please add `arr` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Splice is a method for arrays, not strings. Try this:

```
years = theArtist.years.split('')
let birth = Number(years.splice(0,4))
let death = Number(years.splice(7,4))
```

Alternatively, use substring.

```
let birth = Number(theArtist.years.substring(0,4))
let death = Number(theArtist.years.substring(7,11))
```

Comment: Did you try either of these solutions. Both fail for different reasons

Comment: I didn't, just used OP's indices for a quick answer. Doubled checked the functions and edited to be correct.

Comment: So I fixed the function with that, but now it returns two objects. I just want it to return the name value within the objects that pass that criteria. I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: To clarify, arr is an array of "Artists", which have a "name" and "years" field. You are trying to filter the array down to just the Artists who were born and died between 1900 and 2000. The function is returning an array of Artist objects that match your criteria, but you just want their names (in an array). Is that correct?

Comment: been trying to get this for hours now.

Comment: return result[].name; like how do I get that to give me a response at every iteration of the array

Comment: return result.map(artist => artist.name) should return an array of names.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) on strings (`splice` is a similar function for arrays). Also note your indexes were off by 1 !

```js
var years = "1971 - 1984";
let birth = Number(years.substring(0,4))
let death = Number(years.substring(7,11))
console.log(birth,death)
```

Comment: So I fixed the function with that, but now it returns two objects. I just want it to return the name value within the objects that pass that criteria. I cannot figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use `slice` instead `splice`:

```
'1971 - 1984'.slice(0,4) // '1971'
'1971 - 1984'.slice(7,11) // '1984'
```